# How to show year/months in archive block?

Tags: views, blocks

I want to create a archive block for blogs. I tried by using default archive view block, bot that structure is not suitable for my requirement. I need years to display and when I click on years, months should display like below:

```
           2016
             Jan 2016
             Feb 2016
           2015   
             Jan 2015
             Jan 2015 
           2014
           2013
           2012
```

In the same way after a click on year/month, related data should get display.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, then add the creation date of the blog to your views fields; it will be displayed.

- Create a new view that shows only nodes whose content type is *blog*
- Select the format you want
- In the fields section, add the title and other fields you want to display
- Add the date field
- Save it; you should get what you wanted

Comment: Can you **edit** your question to also explain how to display the ***months*** (as requested in the question)?